# How to use short namespaces with XElements in .Net?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am parsing an XML (RDF specifically) document, basically mapping it to some strongly typed objects in .Net. I have been using this really long syntax for selecting namespaces something like:

```
ontology.Elements("{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}Property")
```

What I really want to do is something like:

```
ontology.Elements("rdf:Property")
```

I know with the older XML framework there was a Namespace Manager you could map namespace short names to the URIs, but not sure how to do the same with XElements. Ideas?

Comment: what is "C#.NET"? I've never heard of it.

Comment: @John http://tinyurl.com/3alulch

Comment: how very clever. If you actually look at the search results, you'll find that there is nothing named "C#.NET".

Comment: @John I know, I got your point the second I read your comment :-) Thanks for the reminder that C# is the language, not C#.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the namespace separately as an `XNamespace`:

```
XNamespace rdf = "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#";
...
ontoloy.Elements(rdf + "Property");
```

I *really* like the way LINQ to XML handles namespaces, personally.